# Why are my particle objects "sticking" to the particle emitter?

Tags: particles

Running Blender 2.83 on Windows 10. I've got one emitter set up to emit objects, and many duplicates of that object; however at all instances, the emitted object seems to "stick" at the emitter.
I've noticed this behavior in multiple .blend files; I've had to go to great lengths to hide the emitters (which, in some cases begin glowing as powerfully as the sun from all the "stuck" emitters) to compensate for this problem.
It it just a "Blender thing"? I noticed this bug filed over a year ago; definitely would have to disagree with the "fixed" status...
https://developer.blender.org/T61109